# Get current value when change select option - Angular2

Tags: html, angular

I'm writing an angular2 component and am facing this problem.

**Description:** I want to push an option value in select selector to its handler when the `(change)` event is triggered.

Such as the below template:

```
<select (change)="onItemChange(<!--something to push-->)">
    <option *ngFor="#value of values" value="{{value.key}}">{{value.value}}</option>
</select>
```

Component Class:

```typescript
export Class Demo{

  private values = [
     {
        key:"key1",
        value:"value1"
     },
     {
        key:"key2",
        value:"value2"
     }
  ]

  constructor(){}
  onItemChange(anyThing:any){
     console.log(anyThing); //Here I want the changed value
  }
}
```

How can I get the value(without using jquery) ?

Answer (score 86, accepted):

There is a way to get the value from different options. check this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/tD3UeHLVK9nKYoDJa68d?p=preview)

component.html

```
<select class="form-control" #t (change)="callType(t.value)">
  <option *ngFor="#type of types" [value]="type">{{type}}</option>
</select>
```

component.ts

```typescript
this.types = [ 'type1', 'type2', 'type3' ];

callType(value) {
  console.log(value);
  this.order.type = value;
}
```

Comment: what is the use of this code here    this.order = {
      type: 'type1'          
  };

Answer (score 38):

In angular 4, this worked for me

template.html

```
<select (change)="filterChanged($event.target.value)">
  <option *ngFor="let type of filterTypes" [value]="type.value">{{type.display}}
  </option>
</select>
```

component.ts

```typescript
export class FilterComponent implements OnInit {

selectedFilter:string;
   public filterTypes = [
     { value: 'percentage', display: 'percentage' },
     { value: 'amount', display: 'amount' }
  ];

   constructor() { 
     this.selectedFilter = 'percentage';
   }

   filterChanged(selectedValue:string){
     console.log('value is ', selectedValue);
   }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

Comment: but how to get "type.display" in filterChanged()

Answer (score 5):

Checkout this working [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/qybOOJJjDDBIGNTq8d2Q?p=preview)

```
<select (change)="onItemChange($event.target.value)">
    <option *ngFor="#value of values" [value]="value.key">{{value.value}}</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks for responding, actually @Mubashir's answer is what I want without reading DOM.

Comment: No problem. Cheers !

Answer (score 2):

For me, passing ($event.target.value) as suggested by @microniks did not work. What worked was ($event.value) instead. I am using Angular 4.2.x and Angular Material 2

```
<select (change)="onItemChange($event.value)">
    <option *ngFor="#value of values" [value]="value.key">
       {{value.value}}
    </option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

**HTML**

```
<h3>Choose Your Favorite Cricket Player</h3>
<select #cricket (change)="update($event)">
    <option value="default">----</option>
    <option *ngFor="let player of players" [value]="player">
        {{player}}
    </option>
</select>
  
<p>You selected {{selected}}</p>
```

**Javascript**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
  
@Component({
  selector: 'app-dropdown',
  templateUrl: './dropdown.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dropdown.component.css']
})
export class DropdownComponent {
  players = [
    "Sachin Tendulkar",
    "Ricky Ponting",
    "Virat Kohli",
    "Kumar Sangakkara",
    "Jacques Kallis",
    "Hashim Amla    ",
    "Mahela Jayawardene    ",
    "Brian Lara",
    "Rahul Dravid",
    "AB de Villiers"
  ]
  selected = "----"
  
  update(e){
    this.selected = e.target.value
  }
}
```

**app.componen.html**

```
<app-dropdown></app-dropdown>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can Use `ngValue`. `ngValue` passes sting and object both.

Pass as Object:

```
<select (change)="onItemChange($event.value)">
    <option *ngFor="#obj of arr" [ngValue]="obj.value">
       {{obj.value}}
    </option>
</select>
```

Pass as String:

```
<select (change)="onItemChange($event.value)">
    <option *ngFor="#obj of arr" [ngValue]="obj">
       {{obj.value}}
    </option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Template:

```
<select class="randomClass" id="randomId" (change) = 
"filterSelected($event.target.value)">

<option *ngFor = 'let type of filterTypes' [value]='type.value'>{{type.display}} 
</option>

</select>
```

Component:

```
public filterTypes = [{
  value : 'New', display : 'Open'
},
{
  value : 'Closed', display : 'Closed'
}]


filterSelected(selectedValue:string){
  console.log('selected value= '+selectedValue)

}
```