# Get value from (change) not working properly

Tags: javascript, angular, object, jhipster

I'm working in an angular project,the project was made using [Jhipster](https://www.jhipster.tech/development/) version 6.9. I want to get the value or index when the user select an option from the list.

```
<select  id="field_entidad"  name="entidad" formControlName="entidad" 
         (change)="detalle($event.target.value)">
         <option
         *ngFor="let entidadOption of entidads; trackBy: trackById; let i = index">
              {{ entidadOption.sigla }}
          </option>
</select>
```

The change method work fine as is showed in [Get current value when change select option - Angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35055088/get-current-value-when-change-select-option-angular2/44237376), however in my .ts component when I try to get the value from my .html I have this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/r3S5a.png

This is the function that get the value in my .ts

```
detalle(event:any) :void {
console.log(event);
}
```

I want to get the number value which is shown in the picture which is in fact the index, but I have spend hours and I could not get this attribute I have search some thing like [How to access the first property of a Javascript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/983267/how-to-access-the-first-property-of-a-javascript-object) and I would to know what mean this in JS.
*"1: Object"*

Thanks a lot, P.S this is my first question

Comment: try add to your options the value, e.g. `<option [value]="entidadOption.sigla">`

Answer (score 1):

You are loading the whole object `entidadOption` on each option's value. If you want just the index you could try something like this:

```html
<select  id="field_entidad"  name="entidad" formControlName="entidad" 
         (change)="detalle($event.target.value)">
         <option [value]="entidadOption.id"
         *ngFor="let entidadOption of entidads; trackBy: trackById; let i = index">
              {{ entidadOption.sigla }}
          </option>
</select>
```

And:

```js
detalle(entidadId:any) :void {
     console.log(entidadId);
}
```

I'm guessing the `id` field is what you want.